# Vertical scroll doesn't work on iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, .net, maui

This is my first project with .net maui and i have a problem with scroll view that doesnt work.
Can you help me looking my code? I think that the scroll is not seeing the "CardBopa" components, because if I replace it with text, the scroll works.

[image]

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls"
             xmlns:componentes="clr-namespace:App_BOPA.Componentes"
             
             x:Class="App_BOPA.Views.Inici">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <componentes:HeaderMain />

        
            
        <ScrollView
            Orientation="Vertical"
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always">
            

            <Grid
                RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto">
                <Image
                    Source="bg_image_banner.png"/>
                <VerticalStackLayout
                    Grid.Row="0">

                <Label
                    Text="Butlletí Oficial Del Principat d'Andorra"
                    FontSize="Title"
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                    Padding="16,32,16,0"/>

                <SearchBar
                    Margin="12,16,12,0"
                    BackgroundColor="White"
                    Placeholder="Que contingui"
                    ios:SearchBar.SearchBarStyle="Minimal"/>

                <Button
                    BackgroundColor="#16A085"
                    Text="Cerca"
                    FontSize="Body"
                    TextColor="#FFFFFF"
                    Margin="16"/>

                </VerticalStackLayout>

                <VerticalStackLayout
                    Margin="16,0"
                    Grid.Row="1">

                    <Label
                        Text="Últims butlletins"
                        FontSize="Large"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                        Padding="0,32,0,8"/>


                    <componentes:CardBopa />

                    <componentes:CardBopa
                        Margin="0,8"/>

                    <componentes:CardBopa
                        Margin="0,8"/>

                    <componentes:CardBopa
                        Margin="0,8"/>
            

                </VerticalStackLayout>

            </Grid>

            
        
        </ScrollView>
       
        
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Tried to add height to scroll

Comment: The vertical stack will allow the scrollview to grow as much as it needs to.  Scrolling only works if the contents of the scrollview are smaller than the scrollview itself

Comment: I changed the stack for a grid and now it's working, I guess the problem was what you said, that the scrollview was smaller due to the stack, and now that it has a grid with a * it gives it more space and it works fine. Thanks.

Comment: Good that grid works. But question about original code: Were there cards that did not fit on screen? If so, then you found a bug with ScrollView + VerticalStackLayout.